# why does this code not work with reactive function?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like this code to refresh the values of the inputs to be refreshed whenever I move the map.

Can anybody tell me why this code does not work? When I replace the "reactive" value in the server side by an "observe" function it does what I want.

`ui.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

shinyUI(navbarPage(
    title="HeatXPlorers", id="nav",
    tabPanel(title="Interactive map",
        div(class="outer",
            leafletOutput(outputId = "map", width="100%", height="100%")
        )
    ),
    tabPanel(title="Producers",
        fluidRow(column(2,
            numericInput(inputId= "minLon_prod",
                label = "Min Longitude", value=2.5)
        ))
    )
))
```

`server.r`

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    # Create the map
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        #input$map_bounds and input$map_zoom are created when the leaflet is     created

        leaflet() %>%
            addTiles(
                urlTemplate = "//{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/jcheng.map-    5ebohr46/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                attribution = 'Maps by <a href="http://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>') %>%
            setView(lng = 2.49, lat = 47, zoom = 6)
    })

    ################ END OF SINGLE TIME EXECUTION
    ## Interactive Map - for map ###########################################

    prodInBounds <- reactive({
        bounds <- input$map_bounds
        updateNumericInput(session, inputId="minLon_prod", value = bounds$west)
    })
})
```

Comment: It seems you just copy&pasted your whole code. Please provide a MINIMAL example as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve this will also help you narrow down your problem.

Comment: There you go. it's the most minimal I could do.

Comment: It is most likely not the best question ever, but doest it really deserve so many down-votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be reduced to the fundamental difference between observer and reactive expression. Let me quote the official documentation for observe:

> An observer is like a reactive expression (...) But unlike reactive expressions, it doesn't yield a result (...) Thus, observers are only useful for their side effects (...).
>
> Another contrast between reactive expressions and observers is their execution strategy. Reactive expressions use lazy evaluation (...) if they are not called then they will never re-execute. In contrast, observers use eager evaluation; as soon as their dependencies change, they schedule themselves to re-execute.

Now lets highlight two things:

- in your code you use `updateNumericInput` as a side-effect so nothing useful is returned, because of that `observe` is a natural choice.
- `prodInBounds` is never used so it is never evaluated and because of that `updateNumericInput` is never called as well.

Comment: Hello zero323, thanks a lot a for your huge contribution to this question. So in this example if I add a text render for example calling prodInBounds() it should work right?

Now lets imagine we ave 5 reactive expressions that are linked (The fifth contains the fourth, the fourth contains the third etc.) If we don't render the fifth reactive expression will non of the 5 reactive expressions execute or only the fifth one?

Comment: If it is called in a context which is actually executed then yes, but I would stick with observer here. There is no benefit of using reactive expression. Regarding chained expressions that's right, if the final one is not executed then there is no reason to execute dependencies.